# Can't access deployed Kubernetes-Dashboard - Error 503

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-dashboard

i folowed guide on official Kubernetes Dashboard github (https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) and now I'm facing problem with accessing it. I used kubectl proxy to redirect internal port outside, but when I try to open address:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

it just ends up with this error:

```yaml
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "error trying to reach service: dial tcp 192.168.23.7:8443: i/o timeout",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

[image: Error]
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots as they are not accessible.

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? Kubeadm, minikube, microk8s...? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Did you setup [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) in your cluster? Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You get a timeout. Check if dashboard pods are working (kubectl get pods -n kubernetes-dashboard)

Answer (score -1):

Check u have enough access control
Check here https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/README.md